# Erro em script de phyton

Tags: python

baixei um script (não sei se é assim que se diz, estou começando a programar exatamente hoje) de um game feito em python mas não consigo executá-lo pois há um erro

> File "C:\Users\mah14\Desktop\Jogo Bliblico.py", line 23
>      """;
>        ^
>   SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Se alguém puder me ajudar a resolver agradeço

```
# *** JOGO BIBLICO *** Algoritmo de Abraao
# (Genesis 18:24-32)
# By Guilherme Jose Ferreira (leodmx@brturbo.com.br)

# Inicio do programa
print ('\n'*100)
print """
# *** JOGO BIBLICO *** Algoritmo de Abraao
# By Guilherme Jose Ferreira (leodmx@brturbo.com.br)

    Neste jogo voce deve convencer a Deus a nao destruir
    Sodoma e Gomorra (Genesis 18:24-32). Algo um tanto
    quanto muito dificil, mas vamos la:

    No prompt "Eu:" Digite:
    --> Senhor, e se houver xyz justos na cidade?
    (Onde 'xyz' corresponde a um numero entre 0 e 999)

    Lembre-se: Digite certo para acabar logo!

    Boa sorte!!!;
(""")
raw_input('\nTecle <ENTER> ')

# Inicio do jogo
print '\n'*100
numjust = 50
while numjust >= 10:
    justos = raw_input('Eu: ')
    try:
        if int(justos[20:23]) == numjust:
            print "Deus: Nao destruirei a cidade por amor dos",numjust,"justos."
            if numjust < 45:
                numjust -= 5
            numjust -= 5
    # Jogo do tipo "quente ou frio"
        elif int(justos[20:23]) > numjust:
            print "Deus: Voce nao deveria pedir por menos justos?"
        elif int(justos[20:23]) < numjust:
            print "Deus: Voce nao gostaria de pedir por mais justos?"
    # Se digitar errado, comeca tudo de novo
    except ValueError:
        print "Deus: Acaso vou destruir as cidades sem consultar Abraao?"
        numjust = 50
raw_input('\nTecle <ENTER> ')

# Fim do jogo
print '\n'*100
print "\nDeus: Anjos, tirem Lo e sua familia de la..."
print "\nAnjos: Sim, Senhor!"
print "\n\n*** GAME OVER!!! ***\n"
raw_input('\nTecle <ENTER> ')
```

Comment: Será necessário você [edit] a pergunta e adicionar o código que gera o erro. Mas já adianto será bem você estudar pelo menos o básico antes de qualquer coisa, incluindo lógica de programação e a documentação do Python.

Comment: Anderson ja adicionei o codigo, e obrigado pela dica

Comment: O código foi escrito em Python 2, já tentou rodar nesta versão?

Comment: não, obrigado pela ajuda

Answer (score 2):

O código foi escrito em Python 2, você pode instalar o Python 2 ou fazer pequenas modificações no código para adaptá-lo ao Python 3. Por exemplo o erro que você esta tendo na linha 23 é por causa do print. No Python 3 print() é uma função, e precisa ser usada com parênteses. Esse (""") não faz sentido. raw_input() não existe no Python 3... e por ai vai.